# C++ Web-framework with cookie and SQL support

Tags: wt, cppcms

Good Evening,

I'm building a website which will will look something like this:
[image: Mockup]
So probably a widget-centred web-framework would be best...

Which C++ web-framework supports cookies (for user-login [session] storage+config storage) and SQL (MySQL or SQLite)?

My information about Wt was outdated, it looks like they now have full-support for cookies (http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/1/topics/2111)

CppCMS however has a vibrant community, and there product seems to scale better.

I will do the diplomatic thing, create a project using both frameworks.

It will be a cutdown version with only:

- User registration
- User login/logout (including redirect if deauthed and trying to access auth-req page)
- Search
- Some basic argument passing of results across screen (see initial wireframe for ref)

Should be an interesting project... I wonder if any have done this in the past?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognise these [Wt (http://webtoolkit.eu/wt)](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) widgets you can use for your app:

- charts: WCartesianChart
- dropdown boxes: WComboBox
- models and filter proxy models: WSortFilterProxyModel, WAbstractItemModel
- the lists (views): WTableView
- layout managers with draggable splitters: WHBoxLayout
- tabs: WTabWidget
- panel on the right: WPanel
- suggestion popup on the left: WSuggestionPopup
- WLineEdit
- database access: Wt::Dbo (an ORM), or anything else you prefer
- cookies are well supported in Wt, see cookie related methods in WEnvironment and WApplication

Simply combine them for your application...

Answer (score 3):

Cookie support and SQL backend support are basic things, so I guess all web frameworks support them.

I am a very happy user of cppcms and I can assure you it can do all the things you ask for.

Cppcms' SQL backend uses cppdb, created by the same developer, which supports MySQL, SQLite, Postgres, and others, in addition to supporting connection pooling and other nice features.

Config storage is easy, using a json format. The cppcms also has a nice caching framework, as well as a nice API to create forms, asynchronous requests, long pulling, etc. The templating engine is both simple and very powerful, allowing for a separation of the interface and the application logic.

What's more, probably the thing I like the most about cppcms, the support is very good. Subscribe to the official cppcms mailing list: Artyom, the cppcms creator, is always very patiently replying to requests. Personally, I wished the people asking for support were contributing more to the cppcms wiki, so remember that when you join us.

[Edit: Actually, I noticed you asked the very same question on the cppcms mailing list in April this year, posting the very same screenshot. Myself and other kindly took the time to answer you, but you never replied nor thanked us for our time and advice. You may continue asking the same question all over the place, but please try to be more appreciative of the people who are giving a bit of their time to answer you. Good social manners never hurt.]

Comment: Thanks, I am definitely considering CppCMS due to Wt's lack of support for cookies.

Comment: The only reason I'm still following up on Wt is because of it's Widget heavy interface support. Does CppCMS have a similar feature (i.e.: In mockup, you'll notice all sorts of visual features, an accordion, top tabs, sidetabs, resizeable sidebar).

Comment: As to your last comment, I only made this mockup yesterday... also, my regular computer at home broke (GFX Card fried) meaning I don't have access to my old Firefox session, I'll check my mailing-list email tonight to read your CppCMS reply.

Thanks

Comment: CppCMS is a great framework, for creating web-apps. Very Scalable, and managed.

Answer (score 1):

[BinaryTiers](http://www.binarytiers.org) provides a complete web development environment, including all the tools that make common web development tasks easier out of the box. Some of the fundamental tools and features built-in BinaryTiers include:

- Forms validation system architecture
- Abstract Publishing Architecture with built-in categorization and content translation
- User account registration and maintenance
- Menu management and friendly URLs
- RSS-feed aggregation and syndication
- System administration and web interface for the GNU C++ compilers
- Coherent programming interface for No-SQL data stores as well as relational databases with Redis and MySQL
- Template System and easy page layout customization
- Modular design that provides high extensibility
- High Speed HTTP Communication (Get, Post, Cookies, Files)
- Built-in Encoding and Encryption functions
- Multiplatform: Linux, BSD, OSX and Windows

Comment: for those coming from PHP-Drupal Background, and wanting to do things in C++, binarytiers is like Drupal in C++. Similar UIs, Similar Apis and hooks calls, you will find yourself at home, but in a compiled language :)

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [ffead-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp), it probably does what you need and provides a lot more...

Comment: This looks pretty decent + rather new. Will there be documentation? :)